# Is there a PEFile for ELF

Tags: python, executable, file-format, elf

I love using the PeFile library for Python to parse PE files.  Is there a similar library for parsing ELF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [pyelftools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyelftools)

It supports `ELF` and `DWARF` binary formats. It is a project which is in active development too.

Comment: The link seems to be broken, I'll edit the reply with a new link if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty old, but it still came to the top of Google when I searched...

A good library is lief - https://lief.quarkslab.com

It has support for elf, pe and macho

Answer (score 0):

There's also pylibelf: https://github.com/crackinglandia/pylibelf

It only supports the ELF format though, and it's read-only. But it's in active development, and the write part is expected soon at the time I write this.